# pm2 via apache server

Tags: linux, apache, pm2

I want to control my pm2 app via apache server. I have tried it via a bash script and php. Here is my index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta c
</head>


<?php
if (isset($_POST['RightOPEN']))
{
exec("/home/pi/startmm.sh");
}
if (isset($_POST['LeftOPEN']))
{
exec("/home/pi/channel4.sh");
}
?>
<form method="post">
<button name="LeftOPEN">Channel 4</button>&nbsp;
<button name="RightOPEN">Mirror</button><br>



</form>
</html>
```

and my channel4.sh is:

```
#!/bin/bash
pm2 stop mm
```

and startmm.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
pm2 start mm
```

Can anyone help? It doesnt seem to work and I get the following errors on my apache log:

```
[PM2][Initialization] Environment variable HOME (Linux) or HOMEPATH (Windows) are not set!
[PM2][Initialization] Defaulting to /etc/.pm2
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/etc/.pm2'
    at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:757:3)
    at sync (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
    at Function.sync (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:77:24)
    at module.exports.Client.initFileStructure (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Client.js:132:25)
    at new module.exports (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Client.js:37:8)
    at new API (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/API.js:107:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/binaries/CLI.js:22:11)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/etc/.pm2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see this is a permission error from `permission denied, mkdir '/etc/.pm2'`. As you are invoking a shell script from the web browser you most likely need to give the `www-data` user permission to execute the script as a root user.

If you edit the sudoers file, most likely: `sudo vi /etc/sudoers`, and add a line similar to this at the end `www-data ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /full/path/to/thescript.sh`, this will allow the shell script to be invoked as a root user from the web browser, meaning it shouldn't fail to create any directories.

You can add a line for each individual script (recommended) or allow all `www-data` to execute all scripts as root (dangerous) but here - `www-data ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:ALL`

Dont forget to restart your server `sudo service apache2 restart`

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I done what you asked me to do in the sudoers file. However it still doesnt work for me. I still get the same errors and some new ones which are below:

`[PM2][Initialization] Environment variable HOME (Linux) or HOMEPATH (Windows) are not set!
[PM2][Initialization] Defaulting to /etc/.pm2
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/etc/.pm2'
 `

Comment: Maybe not the best practice but try this `sudo mkdir /etc/.pm2` then `sudo chmod +x -R /etc/.pm2`

Comment: nope still doesnt like it after doing what you asked me to do. `Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/etc/.pm2/modules'`

Comment: Hmm you can see thats slightly different now. Try `sudo chmod +x /etc/.pm2 -R`

Comment: Ok, try this `sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root`

Comment: tried it and I get : `npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-03-04T13_38_19_085Z-debug.log`

Comment: I would suggest creating a package.json file for your application, seems like that is the problem to me...

Answer (score 0):

This is an error because pm2 doesn't find home variable. There are two steps to solve it.

Step 1. Running apache from your user.

Let's suppose your user name is $USER through which you have started your pm2 process.
Run command `sudo nano /etc/apache2/envvars` and edit below lines with your user.

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=$USER
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=$USER
```

After this run below command to restart apache

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Step 2. Exporting home variable.
Lets suppose your user is $USER , then its home dir path would be /home/$USER .

When running any shell command in PHP first export the HOME variable as shown below

```
shell_exec("export HOME=/home/$USER && your command here 2>&1")
```

You are done, now your pm2 command will execute without any permission issue.